# How to sort list of strings by count of a certain character?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list of strings and I need to order it by the appearance of a certain character, let's say `"+"`.
So, for instance, if I have a list like this:

```
["blah+blah", "blah+++blah", "blah+bl+blah", "blah"]
```

I need to get:

```
["blah", "blah+blah", "blah+bl+blah", "blah+++blah"]
```

I've been studying the `sort()` method, but I don't fully understand how to use the key parameter for complex order criteria. Obviously `sort(key=count("+"))` doesn't work. Is it possible to order the list like I want with `sort()` or do I need to make a function for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) can do it, though you need to specify the `key` argument:

```
In [4]: l.sort(key=lambda x: x.count('+'))

In [5]: l
Out[5]: ['blah', 'blah+blah', 'blah+bl+blah', 'blah+++blah']
```

In this code `key` function accepts a single argument and uses `str.count`  to count the occurrences of `'+'` in it.

As for `list.sort(key=count('+'))`, you *can* get it to work if you define the `count` function like this (with [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller)):

```
count = lambda x: methodcaller('count', x) # from operator import methodcaller
```

Comment: Just remember that this is in place, unlike `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
s = ["blah+blah","blah+++blah","blah+bl+blah","blah"]
print(sorted(s,key=lambda t: t.count('+')))
>>["blah","blah+blah","blah+bl+blah","blah+++blah"]
```